# Numpy vector and matrix addition

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to perform normal vector addition, where one of the operands is an `n x 1` matrix?

Why do I care? Sometimes, a function that should return a vector returns an `n x 1` matrix (because the function would equivalently work element-wise on a matrix). When I want to further work with the returned "vector", I always have to reshape - there must be a better way.

For example:

```
v = np.zeros(shape=(2,1))
w = np.array([1,1])
print('{}, {}'.format(v.shape,w.shape))
```

Prints: (2, 1), (2,)

```
print(v+w)
```

[[1. 1.]
[1. 1.]]

```
print(v+w.reshape((2,1)))
```

[[1.]
[1.]] (the desired output!)

Comment: You can use `.T` for transpose, also if you need to add singleton dimensions, you can use , `w[:,None] to add an extra dimension, when needed. `flatten` is also very useful

Comment: Thanks for the [:None] tip! How would ` .T` help?

Comment: Easier than reshape. `.T` same as transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a bit like you are coming from MATLAB where everything is 2d (scalars size is (1,1)) and the trailing dimension is outermost.  Or a linear algebra that treats 'vectors' as single column matrices.

In `numpy`, 0 and 1d arrays are just a normal as 2d.  A shape like (n,) is common.  By the rules of broadcasting adding a leading dimension is automatic (1,n), but adding a trailing dimension requires user action.  That `a[:,None]` is most idiomatic, though not the only option.

The `v+w` broadcasting logic is

```
(2,1) + (2,) => (2,1) + (1,2) => (2,2)
```

The auto-leading logic avoids ambiguity (what should happen if you try to add a (2,) to a (3,)?).  And since leading dimensions are 'outer-most' it makes most sense to expand in that direction.  MATLAB on the other hand 'naturally' expends and contracts the trailing dimensions.

So to some degree or other a (n,1) shape is more awkward in `numpy`, though it is still relatively easy to create.

Another example of an auto leading dimension:

```
In [129]: np.atleast_2d(np.arange(3)).shape
Out[129]: (1, 3)
```

On the other hand `expand_dims` lets us add dimensions all over the place

```
In [132]: np.expand_dims(np.arange(3),(0,2,3)).shape
Out[132]: (1, 3, 1, 1)
```

Comment: So, your best-practice is to drop the last dimension, if it is 1? Is there any way how I could 'imply' by the *operator* (` + ` here) that I don't want broadcasting, or do I need to use [...,0] with the operand, as @shx2 recommended?

Comment: My issue with leaving it as a vector is: what if I want to multiply vector.transpose * matrix? For a vector of shape (n,), vector.T still has shape (n,) and not (,n)

Comment: What kind of multiply is that?  Any ways, `x[:,None]*M` is idiomatic `numpy` if dimensions require that.  Also functions like `np.sum` have a `keep_dims` parameter if its convenient to retain a (n,1) shape.

Answer (score 1):

If `w` has the desired shape of the result (e.g. `(2,)`), and `v` has the same size (e.g. `(2,1)`, or `(2,)`), this is safe and easy:

```
w + v.reshape(w.shape)
```

Less generally, if all you want is to get rid of the last dimension, knowing it is of length 1, you can do:

```
w + v[..., 0]
```